# 100% height div with JQuery Page Scroller

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

I have a web page, a wrapper with five different divs inside and i'm using query PageScroller for scrollable navigation, so pages are stacked above and below each other. My problem is that when I'm looking at one 'page' I can see the top of the 'page' below, how can I make these divs take up 100% of the viewable space? (height only)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="page 1" class="section"> Content here </div>
        <div id="page 2" class="section"> Content here </div>
        <div id="page 3" class="section"> Content here </div>
        <div id="page 4" class="section"> Content here </div>
        <div id="page 5" class="section"> Content here </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's the set up of the HTML, the class 'section' is used by the jquery to scroll to that div when the navigation is clicked.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).ready(function()
{
   var viewport_height = parseInt($(window).height());
   //stringify
   viewport_height = viewport_height + '';
   viewport_height += 'px';

   $(".section").css("height", viewport_height);
}
```

Comment: also....display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; should be assumed for all of the divs

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I couldn't seem to get that to work. I did find this little bit of javascript which did  the job  though.

 
 $(document).ready(function(){
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
        $('.section').css('min-height', windowHeight);
        });